# how to change the color of a pixel in javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm currently trying to figure out how to change the color of a black pixel into yellow. i understand that yellow has 255 green and 255 red, with 0 blue(i think).
So i'm trying to set the Green and Red to 255 and the blue to 0 but the image continues to remain black. This is my code:

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
print(img);

for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    var newG = 0 - pixel.getGreen();
    var newR = 255 - pixel.getRed();
    var newB = 255 - pixel.getBlue();
    var Black = newG + newR + newB;
    pixel.setGreen(newG);
    pixel.setRed(newR);
    pixel.setBlue(newB);

}
```

by the way, the class "SimpleImage" is an image of a black screen, which I am trying to turn yellow. Let me know if more info is needed, Thanks!

Comment: what library is this?

Comment: There is no `SimpleImage` in JS, you might be using some plugin.

Comment: Can you set-up a live demo?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's more than one way to do this. And many people here are more experienced than me with the graphics APIs.

I would do it by placing the image in a canvas, reading the canvas by iterating through each pixel, make your color change (yes, it's R 255 G 255 B 000) and write to the canvas by iterating through it.

Loading the canvas with the image is simple and explained in many places here and also on w3Schools if you prefer.

```
function colorFilter()
{
  //Access the canvas
  c = document.getElementById("canvas1"); 
  context = c.getContext("2d");

  //Declare variables
  var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
  var data = imgData.data;

  var red = new Array();    
  var green = new Array(); 
  var blue = new Array(); 
  var alpha = new Array();    

  //Read image and make changes on the fly as it's read  
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) 
  {                     
    red[i] = imgData.data[i];
    if (red[i] == 0) red[i] = 255; 
    green[i] = imgData.data[i+1];
    if (green[i] == 0) green[i] = 255;
    blue[i] = imgData.data[i+2]; // no change, blue == 0 for black and for yellow
    alpha[i] = imgData.data[i+3]; // Again, no change
  } 

  // Write the image back to the canvas
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4)  
  {
    imgData.data[i] = red[i];
    imgData.data[i+1] = green[i];
    imgData.data[i+2] = blue[i]; 
    imgData.data[i+3] = alpha[i];   
  } 

  context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

This is my first answer here, it may not be perfect, but I use this regularly, so it does work.

If you're using a 3rd party library, I would think that it's not needed, since the code I used is pure JavaScript.

Hope that helps as much as others here have helped me.

Comment: You're very welcome.  You can mark my reply as the answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. You just need to assign the respective RGB values

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
print(img);

for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    pixel.setRed(255);
    pixel.setGreen(255);
    pixel.setBlue(0);
}
print(img); //Print result
```

Don't forget to print the changed image to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually blacks Rob value is `0,0,0`. So u made a mistake in the values. For green it should be `255-pixel.getGreen()`,for red also `255-pixel.getRed`. Then u have to also put `print(img)` after the for loop for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    pixel.setGreen(255);
    pixel.setRed(255);
}
print(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);

for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    var newR = 255 - pixel.getRed();
    var newG = 255 - pixel.getGreen();
    var newB = 0 - pixel.getBlue();
    var Black = newR + newG + newB;
    pixel.setRed(newR);
    pixel.setGreen(newG);
    pixel.setBlue(newB);
}
print(img);
```